# My python trajectory calculator for a small mass in a gravitational field - why is energy conservation violated?

Tags: orbital-motion, simulations, computational-physics, software, celestial-mechanics

I wrote this thing to calculate the next position of a small mass, given its current position and velocity, and a vector field determines acceleration.

It sort of  works - except I can never get the small mass to stay in a circular orbit - it always deviates and flies off to infinity, even when I set its initial velocity to the critical value for circular motion accurate to 6 decimal places.

Is this due to computer rounding errors, or something more fundamental?

Please see the attached graph. Note that the small mass begins at (0, 7million) and spirals outwards, clockwise.

[image: a trajectory beginning at (0, 7million) and spiralling outwards. it was initially set to have the critical value of velocity for circular motion.]

EDIT: People wanted to see some code so here goes

These are the most important 2 lines (with respect to our discussion)

```
# get next period velocity, vnext, from current period velocity, vt
vnext = (at[0]*deltat + vt[0], at[1]*deltat + vt[1])

# get next period position, pnext, from current period position, pt
pnext = (pt[0] + vt[0]*deltat + 0.5*at[0]*deltat*deltat, pt[1] + vt[1]*deltat + 0.5*at[1]*deltat*deltat)
```

Comment: You are probably using a naive forward Euler integrator. That method has enormous energy errors. An intuitive way to resolve that problem is to correct for the total energy of the system after every integration step.

Comment: Please formulate your questions and answers in clean English, not everybody has English as mother-tongue, s.t. jargon is not clear. What is "sorta"? Does it mean that it seems that works?

Comment: @Sofia rectified

Comment: Could you attach the formulas/code used and the initial conditions? I guess the issue is what CuriousOne said. A Runge Kutta method is quite simple and should correct the problem.

Comment: @CuriousOne OK thanks. I think you're right, tangential velocity increases slightly with each iteration where it should stay the same (in circular orbit). So I will calculate the KE and GPE at each step, and shrink the velocity vector to the magnitude that it _should_ be (keeping its direction the same), so that the sum of KE and GPE at that step doesn't exceed the total energy of the system at the beginning. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @jinawee, bibbly, and CuriousOne. No need for code, by the way it is correct. You can spare yourself hard work! Just see my answer. Kind salutations from me.

Comment: @bibblybobbly: Yes, you got it.Does your potential have central symmetry? In that case you can do even better, because there is a second constant of integration: angular momentum is also conserved. If you correct for both, then your remaining error will only affect the time dependence of the angular velocity of the solution.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks again for the response. Very surprised, the calibre of responses is making me feel very amateur! I'm not exactly sure what you mean by central symmetry, but the field is supposed to model a radial field caused by a planet. Are you saying I could also calculate initial angular momentum, and then adjust the calculated velocities at each step to not exceed that value? But then I didn't understand your last clause about time dependence. Thanks again!

Comment: Somebody please post that as an answer... @CuriousOne?

Comment: ...or @jinawee? By the way, Sofia is right that you can omit the code. This isn't a programming site, and while a short code sample is sometimes useful to _clarify_ the question, we don't really handle questions that rely on including code in your question.

Comment: Actually, I decided I might as well remove it for you. It's really not necessary, seeing as how two commenters (plus me) were able to immediately identify the problem. If you do have questions on this project that require more detailed examination of the code, I'd suggest checking whether you can ask them on [scicomp.SE].

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic: He may get a more precise answer there, probably even a lecture on optimum Hamiltonian integrators...

Comment: If the problem was indeed the naive Euler integrator, which does not conserve energy, Runge-Kutta will not fix the problem (well, it'll make it a bit better, but you'll still see similar behaviour). Rather you'll need a symplectic integrator, such as Verlet or leap-frog, or semi-implicit Euler (I suppose the heuristic method of @CuriousOne should work as well). I think the problem has already been solved (there's so much discussion here that I don't plan on reading everything), but these terms were not mentioned on this page and they might help you in searching for more information.

Comment: @jinawee (many comments up) and anyone else reading this: as a rule of thumb I think we shouldn't be asking for code samples in questions on this site. If a question would benefit from seeing code it's probably a computational question and thus off topic. Though maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what simulation technique you are using, but clearly errors are adding energy to the system.  A simple one would be to take a starting position $(x,y)$ and velocity $(v_x,v_y)$.  Note that if your velocity is not exactly right for a circular orbit, you should just get an ellipse that is close to the circle you are after, so that is not your problem.  You then calculate the the acceleration on the mass $(a_x,a_y)$ and you might use a timestep of $\Delta t$.  Then you update $v_x \to v_x+a_x \Delta t$ and so on.  This has errors of about $(\Delta t)^2$.  If you make $\Delta t$ too small, the updates are so small you get numeric inaccuracy.  If you make $\Delta t$ larger, then $(\Delta t)^2$ becomes larger yet and the model errors get large.  There are other techniques for integrating equations.  A very popular one is Runge-Kutta methods, which can have much smaller model error at the price of some more complexity.  This still doesn't enforce energy conservation, but it may be accurate enough for your purposes.  Any good numerical analysis text will have a discussion. I like the discussion in [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) (obsolete versions are free online with code) but others will have their favorites.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I edited my question to include some of the code.